# Get the value of a class when I check on a multiple options input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of `team-id` when I check it on a multiple options input and save this value on `selectedTeams` array

Common atributtes

```
teams: [],
selectedTeams: [],
```

Array `teams` get all teams on another function and works fine

I'm doing this function

```
GetSelectedTeams: function () {  
    var self = this;
    var selected = $('input:checked').attr('team-id');
    for (var i = 0; i < this.teams.length; i++) {
        if (i == selected){
            self.selectedTeams[i] = true;
        }
    }
    var n = $('input:checked').length;  

    console.log("Selected Team is " + selected);
    console.log("SelectedTeam length is " + self.selectedTeams.length);
    console.log("Teams checked " + n);                  
}
```

The function trigger is

```
    $('#teamsList').on('click','[id^=team]', function() {
        this.GetSelectedTeams();
    });
```

`#teamsList` is the list with all teams

```
<ul id="teamsList" style="list-style-type: none;">
```

And he will add with this structure that works fine

```
        $('#teamsList').append('<li>\
                <input type="checkbox" id="team' + item.Id + '" class="confirmCheckbox" team-id="' + item.Id + '" data-team-id="' + teamId + '" />&nbsp;' + item.teamName + '\
            </li>\
        ');
```

Console shows the same team-id always, the lenght is always 2 and teams checked works fine.

Comment: *I want to get the value of team-id* what is team-id?

Comment: team-id is a class of an input

Comment: Nope, I really can't make head nor tail of this question. Please be more clear

Comment: not multiple ids on teamList

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: You mean, when you click on `<ul id="teamsList"` you want to get tem-id values of all checkboxses which are checked?

Comment: `var selected = $('input:checked').attr('team-id');` is this a way to get elements by class selector ?. As you stated: _`team-id is a class of an input – Paolo Frigenti`_

Comment: @PaoloFrigenti, try out my code given in the answer.

Comment: @Himanshu Upadhyay no, only selected team-id

Comment: @SwapNeil this is what I have and the team-id is repeating when I click another input

Comment: `<ul id="teamsList" ` have `id=teamsList` also your checkbox id start with `id="team' + item.Id + '"`.. and you calling a click event where the selector is `id` start with `team` i.e `$('#teamsList').on('click','[id^=team]', function() {` so in this case even if the check box is clicked it will click ul tag also as its id starts with `team`

Comment: yes @PaoloFrigenti, that is what I said. Did you try my code ? The attribute `data-team-id` is having the team id(s) right ?

Comment: @PaoloFrigenti, I have updated my answer. I would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get selected team id like this:

```
var selectedTeams=[];
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.is(":checked")){
        selectedTeams.push($this.attr("data-team-id"));
    }
});
```

here the variable `selectedTeams` will be having all `teamid` values for all of the checked checkboxes.

Comment: @PaoloFrigenti, I have updated my code once again. Please try this out.

Comment: Thank you @PaoloFrigenti, for accepting my answer and upvoting it in advance. :-)